# Wrap TXMLData in SOAP Body and modify Content-Type in HTTP header

Tags: delphi, soap, http-headers, webservice-client

I have almost the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307943/delphi-wrapping-txmldata-in-soap-request-with-schema-tag), but I would need to send just [MyXML] in SOAP body.
That's like this:

```
POST /soap HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
SOAPAction: "getData"
Content-Length: 1664
Host: abc.com

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xy.com/ns1">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <ns1:metadata>
             <ns1:processGroup>PG</ns1:processGroup>
             <ns1:processName>PN</ns1:processName>
             <ns1:applReqID>445526687456</ns1:applReqID>
             <ns1:receiver>XY</ns1:receiver>
             <ns1:documentVersion>2<ns1:documentVersion>
          </ns1:metadata>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
    <sh:StandardBusinessDocument>
       <sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
          <sh:HeaderVersion>1.0</sh:HeaderVersion>
    ...
    </sh:StandardBusinessDocument>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is it possible in delphi 2010 and how to do that?

Another question is how would I change Content-Type, as you can see the webservice requests to be application/octet-stream?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Rio.OnBeforeExecute handler and you can substitute the XML with anything you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've already done that, but I thought it may be a more elegant way. What about modifying Content-Type?